# stunnel Haproxy ldap authentication

Tags: ldap, authentication, haproxy, stunnel

in our setup port 433 is handled by stunnel. After that haproxy will dispatches the request to the appropriate backend.

I have managed to enable authentication in haproxy. But the users and passwords are sitting in the haproxy.conf file. Is there a way to enable ldap authentication in haproxy or stunnel?